# Validate multiple StartTime and EndTime in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one screen in which there are multiple start time and end time textboxes by weekDay.I want to validate below rules using jquery.

[Day wise Start Time End Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QJcn.jpg)

1. Start Time cannot be more than End Time.
2. End Time cannot be less than Start Time.
3. Next row's Start Time can not be equal or less than previous row's End Time.
4. Validation should be fire on textbox focus out and on final submit button. [Sorry it's not visible in image but assume it's there]

Note:- 1. User can delete any row from any position.
       2. User can make entry from top to bottom and bottom to top.He can leave empty row in between.

I have tried my best to do a validation as I'm less experienced in jQuery but It's not working in case if user leave blank row in between or delete any row.

Any help would be appreciated !!

Thanks in advance. -- Pushkar Rathod

```js
var isStartTimeError = false;
var isEndTimeError = false;

$(document).ready(function () {  
  
$("#btnSave").click(function (e) {
    if(ValidateOnSave())
      {
        alert('Perfect !!');
      }
  });

    $( ".StartTimeSlot" ).focusout(function() {

            var ctrl = $(this).prop('id');
            var start_time = $("#"+ctrl).val();
            $("#"+ctrl).removeClass('form-invalid');
            $("#errorMsg").html('');

            if(start_time != null && start_time != "" && start_time != undefined)
            {
                var ctrls = ctrl.split('_');

                var day = ctrls[1];

                var rank = ctrls[2];

                var validTime = start_time.match(/^(0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\d) [APap][mM]$/);

                if (!validTime) {
                    $(this).addClass('form-invalid');
                    $("#errorMsg").html('Enter valid time for ' + day + '.');
                    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
                    $("#"+ctrl).addClass('form-invalid');
                    return false;
                }

                if(parseInt(rank) > 0)
                {
                    var end_time = $("#txtEndTime_" + day + "_" + parseInt(rank - 1)).val();                    

                    if(end_time != null && end_time != "" && end_time != undefined)
                    {
                        //convert both time into timestamp
                        var stt = new Date("January 24, 1984 " + start_time);
                        stt = stt.getTime();

                        var endt = new Date("January 24, 1984 " + end_time);
                        endt = endt.getTime();

                        if(stt <= endt) {
                            $("#StartErrorMsg").html('Start time must be bigger than last end time.<br/>');
                            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
                            $("#"+ctrl).addClass('form-invalid');
                            isStartTimeError = true;
                            return false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $("#StartErrorMsg").html('');
                            isStartTimeError = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        $( ".EndTimeSlot" ).focusout(function() {

            var ctrl = $(this).prop('id');
            var end_time = $("#"+ctrl).val();
            $("#"+ctrl).removeClass('form-invalid');
            $("#errorMsg").html('');

            if(end_time != null && end_time != "" && end_time != undefined)
            {
                var ctrls = ctrl.split('_');

                var day = ctrls[1];

                var rank = ctrls[2];

                var validTime = end_time.match(/^(0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\d) [APap][mM]$/);

                if (!validTime) {
                    $(this).addClass('form-invalid');
                    $("#errorMsg").html('Enter valid time for ' + day + '.');
                    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
                    $("#"+ctrl).addClass('form-invalid');
                    return false;
                }

                var startCtrl = $("#txtStartTime_" + day + "_" + parseInt(rank));
                var start_time = startCtrl.val();

                if(start_time != null && start_time != "" && start_time != undefined)
                {
                    //convert both time into timestamp
                    var stt = new Date("January 24, 1984 " + start_time);
                    stt = stt.getTime();

                    var endt = new Date("January 24, 1984 " + end_time);
                    endt = endt.getTime();

                    if(stt >= endt) {
                        $("#EndErrorMsg").html('End time must be bigger than start time.<br/>');
                        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
                        $("#"+ctrl).addClass('form-invalid');
                        isEndTimeError = true;
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        isEndTimeError = false;
                        $("#EndErrorMsg").html('');
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#EndErrorMsg").html('Start time cannot be empty.<br/>');
                    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
                    $(startCtrl).addClass('form-invalid');
                    isEndTimeError = true;
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
  

});
  
function ValidateOnSave() {
        
        var days = new Array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday");

        var timeStampFlag = true;
        var message = '';

        var isRecordFlag = true;

        for (var i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
            var dayFlag = false;
            $("#div" + days[i]).find('.StartTimeSlot').each(function (ctrl) {                
                if ($(this).val() != '') {
                    var validTime = $(this).val().match(/^(0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\d) [APap][mM]$/);
                    if (!validTime) {
                        $(this).addClass('form-invalid');
                        timeStampFlag = false;
                        dayFlag = true;
                    }
                }
            });

            $("#div" + days[i]).find('.EndTimeSlot').each(function (ctrl) {
                if ($(this).val() != '') {
                    var validTime = $(this).val().match(/^(0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\d) [APap][mM]$/);
                    if (!validTime) {
                        $(this).addClass('form-invalid');
                        timeStampFlag = false;
                        dayFlag = true;
                    }
                }
            });

            if (dayFlag)
                message += ' Enter valid time for ' + days[i] + '. <br/> ';
        }

        //check all the controls
        var isAllEmpty = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
            var dayFlag = false;
            $("#div" + days[i]).find('.StartTimeSlot').each(function (ctrl) {
                var timeSlotId = $(this).prop('id');
                var t1Id = timeSlotId.replace('txtStartTime', 'txtEndTime');
                var t2Id = timeSlotId.replace('txtStartTime', 'txtMinChild');

                if (!($(this).val() == "" || (($("#" + t1Id).val() == "")))) {
                    isAllEmpty = true;
                }
            });
        }

        if (!isAllEmpty) {
            message += ' Enter atleast one setup details. <br/> ';
            timeStampFlag = false;
        }

        $("#errorMsg").html(message);
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');        
  
  return timeStampFlag;
  
    }


$(document).on("click", ".trash", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        
        var deleteId = $(this).attr("id");

        var idArray = deleteId.split('_');

        var idFirstElem = idArray[1];
        var idSecondElem = idArray[2];
        var divToDel = "rowId" + "_" + idFirstElem + "_"+ idSecondElem;
        $("#" + divToDel).remove();
    });
```

```css
.form-invalid {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.errmessage {
    color: red;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <span id="StartErrorMsg" class="errmessage" ></span>
    <span id="EndErrorMsg" class="errmessage" ></span>
    <span id="errorMsg" class="errmessage" ></span>
</div>
<div id="divMonday" class="Monday" >
 <div id="rowId_Monday_0">
  <input class="StartTimeSlot" type="text" id="txtStartTime_Monday_0" name="txtStartTime_Monday_0" value="08:00 AM" />  
  <input class="EndTimeSlot" type="text" id="txtEndTime_Monday_0" name="txtEndTime_Monday_0" value="08:30 AM" />
  <a title="Delete" id="rowIdIcon_Monday_0" onclick="" href="#" class="trash" >Delete</a>      
 </div> 
 <div id="rowId_Monday_1">
  <input class="StartTimeSlot" type="text" id="txtStartTime_Monday_1" name="txtStartTime_Monday_1" value="09:00 AM" />  
  <input class="EndTimeSlot" type="text" id="txtEndTime_Monday_1" name="txtEndTime_Monday_1" value="09:30 AM" />  
  <a title="Delete" id="rowIdIcon_Monday_1" onclick="" href="#" class="trash">Delete</a>      
 </div>
 <div id="rowId_Monday_2">
  <input class="StartTimeSlot" type="text" id="txtStartTime_Monday_2" name="txtStartTime_Monday_2" value="10:00 AM" />  
  <input class="EndTimeSlot" type="text" id="txtEndTime_Monday_2" name="txtEndTime_Monday_2" value="10:30 AM" />  
  <a title="Delete" id="rowIdIcon_Monday_2" onclick="" href="#" class="trash">Delete</a>      
 </div>
 <div id="rowId_Monday_3">
  <input class="StartTimeSlot" type="text" id="txtStartTime_Monday_3" name="txtStartTime_Monday_3" value="11:00 AM" />  
  <input class="EndTimeSlot" type="text" id="txtEndTime_Monday_3" name="txtEndTime_Monday_3" value="11:30 AM" />  
  <a title="Delete" id="rowIdIcon_Monday_3" onclick="" href="#" class="trash">Delete</a>      
 </div>
 <div>
  <input type="submit" id="btnSave" name="Save" value="Save" />
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just force the user to fill in empty rows, or delete them? Also, i prefer to find similar rows by their class, not by an Id that is incremented by one for every row.

Comment: Thanks @Adder for comment. Well all fields are non mandatory. On lost focus I already find the similar rows by their class. Only the problem which I face how to validate them if user enter data in between.  I don't know how to find the upper row's end time which has value. I tried .parent() and closest() but it's not working. Any other idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Well to give some ideas:
Assign a classes "period begin" and "period end" to the input elements. Get all input elements into lists and then navigate in these lists.

```
//example: Monday
var $begins = $('#divMonday').find('.period.begin');
var $ends = $('#divMonday').find('.period.end');

//example: validate 3nd begin
var valid = false;

var k=2;
if($begins[k].val() != '') {
  for(var j= k-1; j>=0; --j) {
    if($ends[j].val() != '') {
        if(parseInt($begins[k].val()) > parseInt($ends[j].val()))
           valid= true;
        break;
    }
  }
  if(j<0)
    valid = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Adder for suggestion. I would like to know how to get the total count of the control in divMonday because in your example you have taken k=2 which I believe a length of StartTime controls.

Comment: $begins.length is the number of begin elements